# How is $\mathbb Z[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n}]=\{a+b\sqrt{n} \mid a,b \in \mathbb Z \text{ or } a,b \in \mathbb Z +\frac{1}{2}\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb Z$ be square-free.

> If $n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, how is $\mathbb Z[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n}]=\{a+b\sqrt{n} \mid a,b \in \mathbb Z \text{ or } a,b \in \mathbb Z +\frac{1}{2}\}$?

I can see that $\mathbb Z[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n}] \subset \{a+b\sqrt{n} \mid a,b \in \mathbb Z \text{ or } a,b \in \mathbb Z +\frac{1}{2}\}$?

**How do we show the reverse containment?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, $a+b\sqrt{n}=(a-b)+2b(\frac12+\frac12\sqrt n)$.

Note that both $a-b$ and $2b$ are integers, when either $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ or $a,b\in\mathbb Z+\frac12$. This proves $\mathbb Z[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n}] \supset \{a+b\sqrt{n} \mid a,b \in \mathbb Z \text{ or } a,b \in \mathbb Z +\frac{1}{2}\}$.

Comment: I think you meant to write the reverse inclusion in the last sentence.

Comment: Sorry; I will fix that.